# Are non-terminating constexpr functions well-defined?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, undefined-behavior, constexpr, c++14

Consider the following code:

```
constexpr unsigned f(unsigned x)
{
    while (x & 1) x *= 3;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    char a[f(2)];
    char b[f(1)];
}
```

In case it isn't obvious: for odd integers `x`, the function `f` never terminates.

When I compile the above program [with clang on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5bcc70cb191ac4c), `b` seems to be a VLA, but not `a`:

```
warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]

char b[f(1)];
```

Is there a well-defined limit at which the compiler decides to stop evaluation of a constant expression? Or would it be perfectly fine for a conforming compiler to go into an infinite loop? Does `f(1)` yield UB?

Comment: Alternative title: "Does constexpr solve the halting problem?" (kidding, of course)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of things which means that an expression is
not a *core constant expression* is

> -- an invocation of a `constexpr` function or a `constexpr` constructor that would exceed the implementation defined recursion limits;

(fifth point in §5.19/2.).  So the limit is implementation
defined.

Comment: Turns out that C++14 has changed this to just "an expression that would exceed the implementation-defined limits", to cover also non-recursive limits, in this case "Full-expressions evaluated within a core constant expression"

Comment: See Annex B: "Full-expressions evaluated within a core constant expression [1 048 576]."

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yes.  I started looking, and then lost track of the original expression.  It is a good question: there have to be some limits, or the compiler will never stop.

Comment: Right now the correct quotes are in the comments but they should be in the answer so we can delete the comments as obsolete.